# PostgreSQL 15 Job Schedule Issue Using pgAgent 15 Jobs

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

I am trying to schedule a PostgreSQL 15 job using pgAgent 15. pgAgent service is running in Windows services. pgAgent schema is stored in database postgres database that is created while installing pgAgent. My stored procedure is created in database db. In pgAgent job creation process, I selected database db1 in "Steps" and mentioned following command in job in code:
CALL sp_update_ended();

Job statistics is showing its status as "f".

Can you please guide / help to troubleshoot and configure job correctly. Would be thankful.

Regards